# Bones are not right when importing fbx

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a bought rigged model in 3ds max file format that I want to use in Blender. So I selected the mesh and bip rig and exported to fbx. When I imported the fbx to blender 2.8, the bones were out of place. The ends of the bones are facing different directions.
[image]

I'm a beginner in Blender and I'm enjoying learning it now especially with the changes in 2.8. Most of my files are in max or fbx and I really want to practice blender especially using the fast rendering of eevee.

I would appreciate some tips or advice in solving this issue. 
Thanks in advance!! ^_^

Comment: the first thing you should know is that 2.8 is not for production, it is simply to experiment because it still has many failures and is in maintenance, perhaps for the stable version is more efficient
if I were you, I would first do some armor from scratch in order to understand how it works now and why there are models that are not compatible, especially if you configured the fbx exporter wrong

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I already tried doing rigging in blender and it was a good study. I know that 2.8 is in the beta version now and I can't wait for it to release officially. I was just asking around if it's possible now even in beta. Hopefully, the official 2.8 release would solve it.
I did try using 7.9 but I was having a bit of difficulty with the interface before that's why I love the 2.8 beta because it's an easier transition for me.

Comment: jejej I think otherwise so I do not use 2.8 is very ugly
to do rigging in 2.7 or 2.8 is almost the same, you can see a tutorial of rigging in youtube in 2.7 and apply it to 2.8
I will give you 3 tips for the bones maybe that will help to find the problem

Comment: place a bone, enter editing mode, extrude a bone from one end select both with shift + A, in the properties panel look for a tab with a bone, the first control box has the axes of the bone, aside this something which says rotation put it in zero

Comment: in blender 2.79 select the file tab as if you were going to save your file, but look for USER PREFERENCES (CTRL + U), open a new window, THERE you will see a selection box that says pressets, on the right you will see one that says blender, in that selection box you can change the interface with 3DMAX or MAYA shortcuts

Comment: Custom KeyMap https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kpir41ms2L8

Comment: https://youtu.be/0U3NjTvwdWIstart with this video, there is no video 100% effective, you should see several and join the right pieces to fix your problem, I had to watch as 100 videos of rigging, pass from knowing nothing to be intermediate level in 3 years now compile my own blender savores 2.79

Comment: if you read my profile you will find how to contact directly, and I help you

Comment: Related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128273/how-do-you-make-your-model-skeleton-to-look-like-this/128274#128274 . Fbx has many small variations depending on which versions of software you are exporting from. In this case it has mis-interpreted the bone orientations during import, rather than the scale. You could try playing with some of the importer settings, but other than that I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Sazerac I hear you with playing with the importer settings. Some did solve some bone placements but the sizes changed. Hmmm I'm also at a loss here. I could do the rigging and skinning again but what's the point of buying the rig asset. I wanted to save time not gain more. I hope the next blender update can solve this.