# Problem with armature when importing model - disconnected bones

Tags: armature, bones, import

I am working on an imported model I found (it's Machamp from Pokémon Sun and Moon). Of course, I am working on it for personal uses, nothing commercial. It's a .dae file, and it contains armature and references to materials and textures. Everything  seems right, except for the bones. These appear to be disconnected, all of them. This makes it impossible to even apply IKs AFAIK (but I am still an amateur in terms of time spent on Blender). I'll provide an example.

[image: wireframe Machamp with disconnected bones]

As you can see, this does not resemble a skeleton at all. Now, on to the question. Am I doing something wrong? Am I importing it in an incorrect way? Or is it possible that the bones were placed like this from the very beginning? Other models, like Eevee, have some disconnected bones, but the most of them are connected. Thanks in advance, if any additional info is needed, ask right away!

Comment: related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128273/how-do-you-make-your-model-skeleton-to-look-like-this/128274#128274 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144274/bones-are-not-right-when-importing-fbx?rq=1. Unfortunately this ai a quirk of file formats/importers. You can try using a different format if possible or playing with the settings.

Comment: Sazerac I would like to mark your answer as correct, but I don't think I can since it's a comment